# BST - Recursive Insert

Tags: c, data-structures

I have written a recursive insert algorithm for a BST. However, there is a bug in the algorithm. If anyone could please give me a pointer, it will be greatly appreciated. Please not that `y = NULL` in the initial call.

```
    void insert_recursive(Node **root, Node *z, Node *y) {
    // z is the pointer to the node being inserted, and y keeps track of z's parent
    Node *x = *root;

    if (x != NULL) {
        y = x;
        if (z->val < x->val)
            insert_recursive(&(x->left), z, y);
        else
            insert_recursive(&(x->right), z, y);
    }
    else {
        if (y == NULL)
            { *r = z; printf("inserting root, %d\n", z->val); }
        else if (z->val < x->val)
             { y->left = z; printf("inserting left of %d, item %d\n", y->val, z->val); }
        else
            { y->right = z; printf("inserting right of %d, item %d\n", y->val, z->val); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which series of `insert` commands best demonstrate the error?

Comment: Only the first node is inserted as root; the function then doesn't propagate. Thanks...

Comment: the call in a for loop is.. recursive_insert(&root, z, NULL), where z is the pointer to the node being inserted

Comment: Pedantry alert! *"However, there is a bug in the algorithm."* Is rubbing me the wrong way. There is a bug in your implementation. Now, if insertion is working right for a NULL tree, and failing after that you probably want to look at the first half of the `if else`. Also, your parameter names are not very enlightening and you have given us no indication of what the parameters are suppose to be.

Comment: z is the pointer to the node being inserted, and y keeps track of z's parent, as I just indicated in the comment in the code. Thanks for your help, in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be the only problem, but your line

```
else if (z->val < x->val)
```

occurs in the `else` clause of `if (x != NULL)`.  In other words, x is guaranteed to be NULL here.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah my bad. It should be `y->val` NOT `x->val`. I'll accept your answer.